# Getting only first object of Json object from json string

Tags: java, android, json

This is my json object :-

```
{"emp_remark":"right now busy.. please wait",
"emp_loginid":"pra",
"emp_name":"Pragya Patel",
"emp_timein":"18:9",
"emp_id":"1",
"emp_timeout":"18:9",
"emp_emailid":"hsjsnejw",
"emp_mobno":"7879467946",
"emp_desigantion":"Android",
"emp_deviceid":"APA91bFLNsLOz2iiSw9r2NKdlnWCWtNNNb-VTVY3TwmT7Nly88NnSJjJwoLNC3qveU7LSW9QY5t71JAejnkogvQRPXA-uEtnlg-1cve00k_4UhIinUH0Lzs"
}
"emp_remark":"right now busy.. please wait",
"emp_loginid":"deepp",
"emp_name":"deepak",
"emp_timein":"18:18",
"emp_id":"2",
"emp_timeout":"18:9",
"emp_emailid":"deep@gmail.com",
"emp_mobno":"7469467946",
"emp_desigantion":"java",
"emp_deviceid":null
}
{
"emp_remark":"right now busy.. please wait",
"emp_loginid":"amu",
"emp_name":"amul",
"emp_timein":"18:18",
"emp_id":"3",
"emp_timeout":"18:9",
"emp_emailid":"amu@gmail.com",
"emp_mobno":"7469462946",
"emp_desigantion":"java",
"emp_deviceid":"APA91bFLNsLOz2iiSw9r2NKdlnWCWtNNNb-VTVY3TwmT7Nly88NnSJjJwoLNC3qveU7LSW9QY5t71JAejnkogvQRPXA-uEtnlg-1cve00k_4UhIinUH0Lzs"
}
```

now in android, i am getting whole object in a string.. but when i am converting it into json object.. it is getting only 1st object i.e.

```
{
"emp_remark":"right now busy.. please wait",
"emp_loginid":"pra",
"emp_name":"Pragya Patel",
"emp_timein":"18:9",
"emp_id":"1",
"emp_timeout":"18:9",
"emp_emailid":"hsjsnejw",
"emp_mobno":"7879467946",
"emp_desigantion":"Android",
"emp_deviceid":"APA91bFLNsLOz2iiSw9r2NKdlnWCWtNNNb-VTVY3TwmT7Nly88NnSJjJwoLNC3qveU7LSW9QY5t71JAejnkogvQRPXA-uEtnlg-1cve00k_4UhIinUH0Lzs"}
```

Here is my code :

```
  @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls) {

        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        Log.d(TAG, "Url : "+getUrl);
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(getUrl, ServiceHandler.GET);
        Log.d(TAG, "String json :" + jsonStr);
        try {
            employeeDetailsModel = JsonParsing.getEmployeePojo(jsonStr);
            List<EmployeeDetailsModel> employeedesignationList = jsonParsing.getEmployeeDes(jsonStr);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception: in parsing >> " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

now i am another class i.e JsonParsing

```
public static EmployeeDetailsModel getEmployeePojo(String jsonString) throws JSONException{
    EmployeeDetailsModel employeeDetailsModel = null;
    JSONObject jsonObject;

    Log.w(TAG, "String json :" + jsonString);
    if (jsonString != null) {

        jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    }
    Log.w(TAG, "Object json :" + jsonObject);

    List<EmployeeDetailsModel> detailsModelList = new ArrayList<EmployeeDetailsModel>();

    if(jsonObject != null && jsonObject.length() > 0){

            employeeDetailsModel = new EmployeeDetailsModel();
            employeeDetailsModel.setEmpId(jsonObject.getInt("emp_id"));
            employeeDetailsModel.setEmpLoginId(jsonObject.getString("emp_loginid"));
            employeeDetailsModel.setEmpName(jsonObject.getString("emp_name"));
            employeeDetailsModel.setEmpMobNo(jsonObject.getString("emp_mobno"));
            employeeDetailsModel.setEmpEmailId(jsonObject.getString("emp_emailid"));
            employeeDetailsModel.setEmpTimeIn(jsonObject.getString("emp_timein"));
            employeeDetailsModel.setEmpTimeOut(jsonObject.getString("emp_timeout"));
            employeeDetailsModel.setEmpdeviceId(jsonObject.getString("emp_deviceid"));
            employeeDetailsModel.setEmpDes(jsonObject.getString("emp_desigantion"));
            employeeDetailsModel.setEmpDes(jsonObject.getString("emp_remark"));

            detailsModelList.add(employeeDetailsModel);

        for(EmployeeDetailsModel detailsModel : detailsModelList){
            Log.w(TAG, "EMP ID : " + employeeDetailsModel.getEmpId() + " EMP Name : " + employeeDetailsModel.getEmpName());
            Log.w(TAG, "EMP DEVICE ID : " + employeeDetailsModel.getEmpdeviceId());
        }

    }
    return employeeDetailsModel;
}
```

and this is my logcat

```
  5720-15608/com.gatepass D/GateEntryFormActivity: String json :{"emp_remark":"right now busy.. please wait","emp_loginid":"pra","emp_name":"Pragya Patel","emp_timein":"18:9","emp_id":"1","emp_timeout":"18:9","emp_emailid":"hsjsnejw","emp_mobno":"7879467946","emp_desigantion":"Android","emp_deviceid":"APA91bFLNsLOz2iiSw9r2NKdlnWCWtNNNb-VTVY3TwmT7Nly88NnSJjJwoLNC3qveU7LSW9QY5t71JAejnkogvQRPXA-uEtnlg-1cve00k_4UhIinUH0Lzs"}{"emp_remark":"right now busy.. please wait","emp_loginid":"deepp","emp_name":"deepak","emp_timein":"18:18","emp_id":"2","emp_timeout":"18:9","emp_emailid":"deep@gmail.com","emp_mobno":"7469467946","emp_desigantion":"java","emp_deviceid":null}{"emp_remark":"right now busy.. please wait","emp_loginid":"amu","emp_name":"amul","emp_timein":"18:18","emp_id":"3","emp_timeout":"18:9","emp_emailid":"amu@gmail.com","emp_mobno":"7469462946","emp_desigantion":"java","emp_deviceid":"APA91bFLNsLOz2iiSw9r2NKdlnWCWtNNNb-VTVY3TwmT7Nly88NnSJjJwoLNC3qveU7LSW9QY5t71JAejnkogvQRPXA-uEtnlg-1cve00k_4UhIinUH0Lzs"}
  07-20 11:32:45.371 5720-15608/com.gatepass W/JSON PARSING CLASSS: Object json :{"emp_remark":"right now busy.. please wait","emp_loginid":"pra","emp_name":"Pragya Patel","emp_id":"1","emp_timein":"18:9","emp_timeout":"18:9","emp_mobno":"7879467946","emp_emailid":"hsjsnejw","emp_desigantion":"Android","emp_deviceid":"APA91bFLNsLOz2iiSw9r2NKdlnWCWtNNNb-VTVY3TwmT7Nly88NnSJjJwoLNC3qveU7LSW9QY5t71JAejnkogvQRPXA-uEtnlg-1cve00k_4UhIinUH0Lzs"}
  07-20 11:32:45.371 5720-15608/com.gatepass W/JSON PARSING CLASSS: EMP ID : 1 EMP Name : Pragya Patel
  07-20 11:32:45.371 5720-15608/com.gatepass W/JSON PARSING CLASSS: EMP DEVICE ID : APA91bFLNsLOz2iiSw9r2NKdlnWCWtNNNb-VTVY3TwmT7Nly88NnSJjJwoLNC3qveU7LSW9QY5t71JAejnkogvQRPXA-uEtnlg-1cve00k_4UhIinUH0Lzs
```

In json object, getting only 1st object

Comment: The JSON is invalid, if you want to put several object together you must separate them and put them inside an array.

Comment: tour JSON data format is invalid..please cheak

Comment: @Pragya Patel check your json using [this](http://pro.jsonlint.com/)

Comment: I have already checked it.. and it showing correct

Answer (score 0):

It is a malformed JSON`,` the correct one would be like this:

`[
   {
    "emp_remark": "right now busy.. please wait",
    "emp_loginid": "pra",
    "emp_name": "Pragya Patel",
    "emp_timein": "18:9",
    "emp_id": "1",
    "emp_timeout": "18:9",
    "emp_emailid": "hsjsnejw",
    "emp_mobno": "7879467946",
    "emp_desigantion": "Android",
    "emp_deviceid": "APA91bFLNsLOz2iiSw9r2NKdlnWCWtNNNb-VTVY3TwmT7Nly88NnSJjJwoLNC3qveU7LSW9QY5t71JAejnkogvQRPXA-uEtnlg-1cve00k_4UhIinUH0Lzs"
   },
   {
    "emp_remark": "right now busy.. please wait",
    "emp_loginid": "deepp",
    "emp_name": "deepak",
    "emp_timein": "18:18",
    "emp_id": "2",
    "emp_timeout": "18:9",
    "emp_emailid": "deep@gmail.com",
    "emp_mobno": "7469467946",
    "emp_desigantion": "java",
    "emp_deviceid": null
   }, 
   {
    "emp_remark": "right now busy.. please wait",
    "emp_loginid": "amu",
    "emp_name": "amul",
    "emp_timein": "18:18",
    "emp_id": "3",
    "emp_timeout": "18:9",
    "emp_emailid": "amu@gmail.com",
    "emp_mobno": "7469462946",
    "emp_desigantion": "java",
    "emp_deviceid": "APA91bFLNsLOz2iiSw9r2NKdlnWCWtNNNb-VTVY3TwmT7Nly88NnSJjJwoLNC3qveU7LSW9QY5t71JAejnkogvQRPXA-uEtnlg-1cve00k_4UhIinUH0Lzs"
  }
 ]`

Comment: Please tell me How to get the correct format of json using Java

Comment: You need to change the JSON which you are getting from the server.
Not anything in your Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string in a JsonArray.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(str);
```

then use the below code.

```
 JsonObject jsonObject;
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a normal jsonList like [{a:"1",b:"2"},{c:"3",d:"4"}],so you can only get first object. 
object like this:{key,value}
list like this:[collection, collection]

Comment: Please add as much as information in the answer it self, Using external links are not recommended since they can be broken later or can be changed the content.