# Android JSON string to JSONArray

Tags: php, android, json

In my project I get data from php server, this data in JSON syntax.
Then my application get this data from the server with simple http request and save that into a string. Now the problem is in the process of converting this string into JSON object and JSONArray.

Server return data -

> {"lat":"35.241","lng":"76.845","name":"AAA"}{"lat":"38.247"lng":"76.852","name":"GGG"}

Get the string from the server and convert to JSON -

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    String url = "http://placePPP.com/hr.php?request=1";
    String response = MyHttpRequest(url);
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The **response** data equal to the Server return data (there is no problem), But after the conversion to the JSON I get only the first part of the string I try to convert -

> {"lat":"35.241","lng":"76.845","name":"AAA"}

I would love if someone can help me to understand why I get only the first part and how can I convert this string into a JSON object and to JSONArray in the best way thanks.

Comment: Json is not correct, it should have enclosing json Array like this [{
 "lat": "35.241",
 "lng": "76.845",
 "name": "AAA"
}, {
 "lat": "38.247",
 "lng": "76.852",
 "name": "GGG"
}]

Answer (score 0):

It is a malformed JSON, that's why you only have the first part.

Look at [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38473704/6644403) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It's not valid JSON, you have two json objects next to each other.

Comment: It should be a comment not and answer.

Answer (score 0):

talk with developer to send data in object or then your data as

```
jsonMainobject {
{"lat":"35.241","lng":"76.845","name":"AAA"}{"lat":"38.247"lng":"76.852","name":"GGG"}
}
```

or you can done as

```
jsonarray[
{"lat":"35.241","lng":"76.845","name":"AAA"}{"lat":"38.247"lng":"76.852","name":"GGG"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server is not producing valid JSON response. Check here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

**Valid response would look like this:**

```
[
 {"lat":"35.241", "lng":"76.845", "name":"AAA"},
 {"lat":"38.247", "lng":"76.852", "name":"GGG"}
]
```

Also parse it with `JsonArray` to get an array of two `JsonObject`s inside.

Comment: Grate, I add the missing bracket and now when I try to parse it with  the JSONArray I get the next error - "org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array"

this is the cod part - 
 JSONArray json_Array = null;
        try {
            json_Array = new JSONArray(response);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: Please check on linked website that the json is a valid one

Answer (score 0):

Change string from

```
{"lat":"35.241","lng":"76.845","name":"AAA"}{"lat":"38.247"lng":"76.852","name":"GGG"}
```

to

```
[{
   "lat": "35.241",
   "lng": "76.845",
   "name": "AAA"
},
{
   "lat": "38.247",
   "lng": "76.852",
   "name": "GGG"
}]
```

For check valid `json` can use this link : http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/